# How can I save feet and inches in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
function inchesTodecimal($inches){
 return $decimal=inches/12;
}
```

I want convert inches to decimal like 11=0.917. I want to save 11 inches in database like decimal number 0.917.there is a problem occur when inches is 10.In float type .10=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you convert your feet Inches in to feet decimal like 5 feet and after point value convert it into decimal like 11=9.17 then insert into your database. When you want to show on user end you convert again feet Decimal to feet Inches like 5.917=>5.11 its simple hope you got what you want...

Here my simple code for conversion:

```
function feetInchesToDecimal($feetinches,$precision = 3){
   list($feet,$inches) = explode(".",$feetinches);
   $inches = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/','',$inches);
   $inches = $inches + ($feet * 12);
   return round($inches /12,$precision);
}

function feetDecimalToInchs($feetdecimal){
    $feet=(int)$feetdecimal;
    $inches=round(($feetdecimal-$feet)*12);
    $feetinches=$feet;
    if($inches>0) $feetinches.=".".$inches;
    return $feetinches;
}

echo feetInchesToDecimal(5.11); //5.917
echo feetDecimalToInchs(5.917); //5.11
```

Comment: thanks,it work fine

Comment: Then mark this answer as accepted

Comment: @ali am new here..
i do what i can do to help you so welcome...

Comment: I think a better approach would be to store the data as total inches in the database so that it can be an integer, and then use getters and setters (mutators) to convert to feet and inches. Do you REALLY need to convert inches to a decimal of feet?